Error "iOS projects must build with PublishTrimmed=true" when Trimming is disabled
In my .NET MAUI App I use DevExpress.Maui in Version 24.1.4 as a dependant NuGet package. With this version trimming is not supported and so I wanted to disable it correctly.
In my Project Properties > Build > Publish, I disabled Publish trimmed and in Project Properties > Android, I disabled Enable trimming
In the Project Properties > Build Publish it looks as follows:

But still, when I compile the project for iOS, I get the following error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)      iOS projects must build with PublishTrimmed=true. Current value: False. 
Set 'MtouchLink=None' instead to disable trimming for all assemblies.   MyApp (net8.0-ios)  
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5\17.5.8018\targets\Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets    
303 

Therefore, I changed the Linker behavior to Don't link:

What do I influence with these settings and why not Link All or Link SDK only with these settings?

The settings to disable trimming and the necessary changes for Android are also reflected in the XML of my csproj:
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net8.0-android|AnyCPU'">
  <RunAOTCompilation>False</RunAOTCompilation>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net8.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
  <MtouchLink>None</MtouchLink>
</PropertyGroup>

(Don't know why RunAOTCompilation and Trimming disabled don't even work hand in hand on Android?)


But, even with these settings I still get the following error during compile for iOS:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)      iOS projects must build with PublishTrimmed=true. Current value: False. 
Set 'MtouchLink=None' instead to disable trimming for all assemblies.   MyApp (net8.0-ios)  
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5\17.5.8018\targets\Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets    
303 

Hint: I use XCode 15.2 with Command Line Tools 15.1 on my Mac and currently use <MauiVersion>8.0.70</MauiVersion> or even newer with the Nightly builds.


How do I have to change my csproj so that it works and compiles correctly and Trimming is disabled and the dependant DevExpress.Maui component can work correctly?
=================== Update ===================
As asked in the comment, here is my complete Project File (csproj):
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android;net8.0-ios</TargetFrameworks>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>TestApp</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <MauiVersion>8.0.70</MauiVersion>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>TestApp</ApplicationTitle>
        
        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.companyname.testapp</ApplicationId>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">14.2</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        
        <PublishTrimmed>False</PublishTrimmed>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net8.0-ios'">
        <EnableAssemblyILStripping>false</EnableAssemblyILStripping>
        <CodesignKey>Apple Development: Created via API (KUM72ZTF8D)</CodesignKey>
        <CodesignProvision>VS Codesign Provisioning Profile</CodesignProvision>
        <ProvisioningType>manual</ProvisioningType>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net8.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
        <MtouchLink>None</MtouchLink>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net8.0-android|AnyCPU'">
        <RunAOTCompilation>False</RunAOTCompilation>
    </PropertyGroup>


    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.png" Resize="True" BaseSize="300,185" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="ViewModels\Messages\" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- Splashscreen for Android -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="Resources\Splash\mo_splash.png" Color="#000000" BaseSize="1024,1024" Resize="false" />
        <None Update="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <!-- Splashscreen for iOS -->
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net8.0-ios'">
        <InterfaceDefinition Include="LaunchScreen.storyboard" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.80" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="8.0.80" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Maui.Core" Version="24.1.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView" Version="24.1.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Diagnostics" Version="8.2.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="9.0.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.2.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="LocalizationResourceManager.Maui" Version="1.2.1" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Update="Platforms\Android\LocalizationService_Android.cs">
        <ExcludeFromCurrentConfiguration>false</ExcludeFromCurrentConfiguration>
      </Compile>
      <Compile Update="Platforms\iOS\MauiProgram.iOS.cs">
        <ExcludeFromCurrentConfiguration>false</ExcludeFromCurrentConfiguration>
      </Compile>
      <Compile Update="Resources\Localization\AppResources.Designer.cs">
        <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
        <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
        <DependentUpon>AppResources.resx</DependentUpon>
      </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Update="Resources\Localization\AppResources.resx">
        <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
        <LastGenOutput>AppResources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <MauiXaml Update="Pages\Help.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
      <MauiXaml Update="Pages\Settings.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
    </ItemGroup>    

</Project>


Can you add the full code of the .csproj file？

Sorry for my late response! I added the entire .csproj to my original question so you can see it. In a different post, somebody mentioned that trimming is mandatory on iOS - is this correct and how would I disable trimming then when it is not allowed with the DevExpress version that is referenced in the .csproj?
